When I learned Sleuth, I found that it was outdated, so I used Micrometer Tracing to replace it. How to integrate Spring Stream + RabbitMQ +Zipkin
When I learned Sleuth, I found that it was outdated, so I used Micrometer Tracing to replace it. How to integrate Spring Stream + RabbitMQ +Zipkin
I've already connected Zipkin directly, but I don't understand how to transfer through rabbitMQ
Add dependencies:
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>  
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>  
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>

Configure:
management:  
  tracing:  
    sampling:     
      probability: 1.0
  zipkin:  
    tracing:  
      endpoint: http://192.168.31.112:9411/api/v2/spans

zipkin:
docker run -d -p 9411:9411 --name zipkin -e RABBIT_ADDRESSES=192.168.31.112:5672 -e RABBIT_USER=rabbit -e RABBIT_PASSWORD=rabbit112 openzipkin/zipkin

How can I modify it to achieve Sleuth's effect:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>

spring:
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
      rate: 1000
  zipkin:
    sender:
      type: rabbit
    rabbitmq:
      addresses: 127.0.0.1:5672
      queue: zipkin

Want to achieve in the end: zipkin.sender.type=rabbit
How can I implement it, or which documents can be helpful?

I found a module with similar functions, but it shouldn't be what I wanted:
zipkin-reporter-java
